# text alignment for webpage

Tags: html, css

[image]

i'm looking to duplicate the code on the left of the screen and have it sitting on the right of the image. I have tried float left although this is just jumbling up the text and it's not correctly sitting alongside the iphone image. services 2 on the css is for the right side text on the screen and the services css is for the text on the left of the screen. Here is my code.

```
 <div class="services2">
            <p> Screen Repair <span><br/>Example: Cracked glass/touch 
  screen, dark ink like blemishes, touch screen non responsive, screen 
 discolouration. <br/><br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p> External Button Repair <span><br/> Example: sleep wake 
 button unresponsive, volume up and volume down buttons no longer working 
 correctly, home button not working <br/><br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p>Battery Repair <span> <br/> Example: where you have to charge 
 your device more often than usual and the device runs out of power quicker 
 and quicker.<br/> <br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p> Charging Port Repair <span><br/> Example: whilst plugged in 
    your device no longer charges up. </span> </p>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.services{
width:25%;
margin-left:2%;
margin-top:2%;}


.services p{
font-family:narrow;
font-size:21px;
text-align:center;}


.services span{
text-align:center;
font-family:narrow;
font-size:18px;
color:#525353;}



.services2{
width:25%;
margin-left:2%;}


.services2 p{
font-family:narrow;
font-size:21px;
text-align:center;}

.services2 span{
text-align:center;
font-family:narrow;
font-size:18px;
color:#474747;}
```

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox?

Comment: @k185 yes i've tried flex direction. still not working.

Comment: I have done this pen, if this is what you are looking for 
https://codepen.io/k185/pen/eWdwop?editors=1100

Comment: @k185 all the elements are stacked? not displaying in a row? they're all in collumn format

Comment: attach an image of what you want to your question, I think I am a bit confused

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ENdCp

Comment: stacking like that^^

Comment: I changed the pen, check it

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lLYcy still no luck

Comment: @k185 still no luck ^^

Comment: Flexbox should be the answer to this, just keep doing research. Or update your question to ask how to fix it with flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Always use a wrapper.
Set the wrapper width as much you want.You can change it to bring it to exact right of image.
Set wrapper text-align property to left.
Period.

```css
#wrapper {
float:right;
width:30%;
text-align:left;
}
.services{
margin-left:2%;
margin-top:2%;}


.services p{
font-family:narrow;
font-size:21px;
text-align:center;}


.services span{
text-align:center;
font-family:narrow;
font-size:18px;
color:#525353;}



.services2{
margin-left:2%;}


.services2 p{
font-family:narrow;
font-size:21px;
text-align:center;}

.services2 span{
text-align:center;
font-family:narrow;
font-size:18px;
color:#474747;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="services2">
            <p> Screen Repair <span><br/>Example: Cracked glass/touch 
  screen, dark ink like blemishes, touch screen non responsive, screen 
 discolouration. <br/><br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p> External Button Repair <span><br/> Example: sleep wake 
 button unresponsive, volume up and volume down buttons no longer working 
 correctly, home button not working <br/><br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p>Battery Repair <span> <br/> Example: where you have to charge 
 your device more often than usual and the device runs out of power quicker 
 and quicker.<br/> <br/> </span> </p>
            </div>



    <div class="services2">
            <p> Charging Port Repair <span><br/> Example: whilst plugged in 
    your device no longer charges up. </span> </p>
            </div>
            
 <div>
```